# Django checking unique Field Entries between two fields

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a problem where I have to store two IP fields for a given user from the Admin Page. 
My user model is defined as follows:

```
class userIPs(models.Model):
   IP_Address_1 = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=False)
   IP_Address_2 = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=False)
   class Meta:
     unique_together = (('IP_Address_1', 'IP_Address_2',),)
```

OR

```
IP_Address_1 = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=False, unique = True)
IP_Address_2 = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=False, unique = True)
```

Using either implementations, I was able to only check for uniqueness in one particular IP field.

e.g: If user1 has the following values,

> IP_Address_1 = 10.0.0.1; IP_Address_2 = 10.0.0.2

If I try to add same values, the system raises an exception as expected.
But,when I try to add other users values like

> IP_Address_1 = 10.0.0.2; IP_Address_2 = 10.0.0.1

the values are added without any unique checking.

I wanted to make sure the IP is unique by checking both IP_Address_1 and IP_Address_2.
Is there a way to check multiple fields for uniqueness?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to check if (IP1 and IP2) are unique or does any address have to be unique? In other word: if user 1 has IP1 and IP2 should user 2 with IP1 and IP3 pass?

Comment: I want the IP address to be unique for all the users. i.e., If user1 has IP1, IP2, then user 2 must have IP3, IP4 and so on

Comment: Then refactor the model to have only one IP address per model (row), have that be unique and ensure elsewhere that a single user has no more than 2 instances of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to check multiple fields for uniqueness?

You can update `save` method for your model to check if both IP's are unique.

Something like that:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not (userIPs.objects.filter(IP_Address_1=self.IP_Address_1).exists() and userIPs.objects.filter(IP_Address_2=self.IP_Address_2).exists())
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        print "IP not unique"
```

Comment: This implementation works exactly like my current unique=True, for some reason, it checks only the IP_address_1, IP_address_2  fields separately and doesnt check for values in each others fields.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: I'm the one who asked the question. Thought the answer might be useful to someone.

To validate values in two different fields, we can use:

1. `unique=True` for uniqueness in the same field

and

2. `def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):` function to validate against other field.

So, my final **model** is as the following

```
class userIPs(models.Model):
   IP_Address_1 = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=False, unique = True)
   IP_Address_2 = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=False, unique = True)

   def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if (userIPs.objects.filter(IP_Address_2=self.IP_Address_1).exists()):
           raise ValidationError('IP Address 1 value already exists.')
       elif (userIPs.objects.filter(IP_Address_1=self.IP_Address_2).exists()):
           raise ValidationError('IP Address 2 value already exists.')
       else:
           super(userIPs, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
   
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the "order" of the two IP addresses matters, simply sort them in your `save()` and trust your database for the rest.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.ip1, self.ip2 = sorted((self.ip1, self.ip2))
    return super(UserIps, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT:

For the requirement

> I want the IP address to be unique for all the users. i.e., If user1 has IP1, IP2, then user 2 must have IP3, IP4 and so on

it's better to refactor:

```
class IpAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ip = models.GenericIpAddressField(unique=True)
```

and ensure you never have more than two (or whatever your business requirement is) `IpAddress`es per `user`.

Comment: Hi @AKX, thanks for the answer, my current IpAddress class is similar to this, but has two IP fields, what do you exactly mean by refactor?  I'm a newbie to Django